# How to parse XML in javascript Nashorn engine?

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml-parsing, xmldom, nashorn

I am trying to run javascript on server side (with Nashorn) and, inside the javascript code, parse an XML file.
We can't do it by default : we need to load some specific .js library (DOMParser, etc).

I have tryied to use Node.js module 'XMLDOM', which could be used without Node.js as shown here : https://github.com/jindw/xmldom/wiki/How-to-use-xmldom-in-non-node.js-JavaScript-platforms-like-Rhino-or-SpiderMonkey

But this page bring a new problem : we need to encapsulate the load of these .js file inside objects, they give us an example :

```
var dpObj = {};
loadObject ( dpObj, "dom-parser.js" );
```

(if we just load the .js files in a classic way, it doesn't work)

I have no idea how to code such a 'loadObject' function, but it could be the solution. Maybe we could also could use the 'require' library inside Nashorn ? Maybe there is a good alternative to XMLDOM module ?

Any suggestions ?

PS 1: I have tryied 'env.rhino.1.2.js' (http://www.envjs.com) as XMLDOM module alternive but this script can even not be loaded by Nashorn...

PS 2: I have also tryied to parse XML in Java and use the result inside Javascript but I don't know how to convert the object (I have a org.w3c.dom.Document object which is inserted but this is not the same as the javascript dom document... I have for example the gesDescendant method missing or something like this).

Answer (score 1):

Nashorn supports load and  loadWithNewGlobal primitives.

'load' loads a script from a URL, a file into the current global scope.

'loadWithNewGlobal' loads the given script into a new global scope. This will avoid polluting the current global scope with the global definitions from the loaded script file/URL.

Additional info on these is at "openjdk nashorn extensions" wiki.

(Unrelated) you could actually parse XML documents using Java XML parser APIs as nashorn supports calling arbitrary Java API from script code. You can do conversions using Object.bindProperties (another extensions documented in nashorn wiki)

Comment: Thanks ! Unfortunately, the simple load of dom-parser.js fail (from XMLDOM Node.js module) :
`var dpObj = loadWithNewGlobal("src/main/resources/js/xmldom/dom-parser.js");
print("dpObj : " + dpObj);`
Will print :
dpObj : undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined, ...
Maybe I should try your second solution

Comment: Can you please give an example for the xml parsing in java + binding in javascript ? For example, you enter in your JS code with an arg (a java Dom Document) and have to call a function foo wich take a "Javascript Document".
For information, all this is for Blockly : the idea is to generate JS code on the server side. Since the conversion functions exist only in JS, I have to execute JS function inside Nashorn.